# Why is the else statement not executed?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
import random

words = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

wins, loss = 0, 0

while True:

    word = random.choice(words)

    ur_word = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors..: ")

    print("\nComputer: {0}\nYou: {1}\n".format(word, ur_word))

    if word == ur_word:
        print("Tie!")
        continue
    elif ur_word == 'q':
        break
    elif word == 'Rock':
        if ur_word == 'Paper':
            print("You won!")
            wins += 1
        elif ur_word == 'Scissors':
            print("You lost!")
            loss += 1
    elif word == 'Paper':
        if ur_word == 'Rock':
            print("You lost")
            loss += 1
        elif ur_word == 'Scissors':
            print("You won!")
            wins += 1
    elif word == 'Scissors':
        if ur_word == 'Rock':
            print("You won!")
            wins += 1
        elif ur_word == 'Paper':
            print("You lost!")
            loss += 1
    else:                                        <<<<---------///----------HERE------------///----
        print("Please enter a valid input.")


    if wins == 3:
        print("\n\tYou won the entire game of three rounds!")
        break
    elif loss == 3:
        print("\n\tYou lost the entire game of three rounds!")
        break
```

**Now, my question is: why does the selected else statement not execute when I enter an arbitrary value like "74n9wndwekf"?

A guy told me that you cannot execute `if` and `elif` statements after an `else` statement, and also that you cannot execute your code after a `break` statement. I don't understand what he meant and I don't know whether this information is of any value to you.**

Comment: Check your indentation; is the `else` actually attached to the `while` loop?

Comment: In your own words, why do you expect the `else` statement to execute? In particular: what is the name of the variable that contains `74n9wndwekf`? What happens in the previous `elif` cases?

Comment: yes, it is attached to the `while` loop.

Comment: You are checking for `word` and not (the horribly misspelled version of) `your_word`. So you end up in the `elif` block that belongs to one of the random words, which means you can never get into the `else`

Comment: else will never execute since one of the elif will always execute.

Comment: Karl's comment is also correct: `word`, by definition, will be one of `Rock`, `Paper`, or `Scissors`, so one of those three `elif`s will always match.

Comment: There is no variable that contains `74n9wndwekf`. Since tha game is rock,paper,scissors the elifs are checking for those three word combinations. If the the user entered word is an arbitrary word like `74n9...` and not paper or rock or scissors the else is supposed to execute.

Comment: Aha, tnx guys :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `else` never happens because one of your `elif`s will always be true.  `word` will **always** be one of `Rock`, `Paper`, or `Scissors` so you'll never hit that `else`.

A simple fix would be to restructure that chain of `if...elif` to check `ur_word` first.

Another way to go would be to validate the input before you do anything else, e.g.:

```
ur_word = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors..: ")
if ur_word not in {'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'q'}:
    print("Please enter a valid input.")
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement, you are checking the following:

- if the computer's random choice is "Rock", do this..,
- else if it is "Papers", do that..,
- else if it is "Scissors", do that..,
- else print invalid input.

The problem here is that the computer's random choice will always be either "Rock", or "Paper", or "Scissors", so one of the first three if/elif conditions will be met, therefore your else block will never be reached.

Try designing your if statements to check for the user input first instead of the computer's choice.